# Postgres Error (Getting PLJava set up)

Tags: java, linux, unix, postgresql, pljava

I have been struggling with a problem trying to get PLJava to work on PostgreSQL on RHEL.

Here is what I have (based off of this:  [PL/Java README](http://cvs.pgfoundry.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/pljava/org.postgresql.pljava/docs/readme.html?rev=1.16&content-type=text/html))

**.cshrc**

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk1.6.0_17/
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/i386
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/i386/client
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/i386/native_threads
setenv PG_DATA /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

**log output**

```
DEBUG:  find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying "/usr/lib/pgsql/pljava"
DEBUG:  find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying "/usr/lib/pgsql/pljava.so"
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/pgsql/pljava.so": libjvm.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

Can anyone tell me what this actually means?

```
libjvm.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

I realize this is a pretty specific question, but I am really struggling with this and any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to turn off SELinux in RHEL